# Defining Projection For NetCDF Files Using Lat/Lon raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, netcdf

I've downloaded and extracted AMSR2 sea ice concentration netCDF files from [here](ftp://ftp-projects.zmaw.de/seaice/AMSR2/3.125km/). Then I tried using the "Define Projection" tool in ArcGIS 10.4 (on Windows 10) to define their spatial reference (and "Edit" spatial reference in ArcCatalog). Based on the [documentation](ftp://ftp-projects.zmaw.de/seaice/AMSR2/README.txt), I guessed it was a custom NSIDC North Pole Stereographic projection.

Unfortunately it does not overlay with my other data in that projection at all. Under "Grid Description" in the documentation, it says

> ## 3. Grid Description
>
> The data is displayed in two polar stereographic maps per day, one for
>   the Arctic (Arc) and one for the Antarctic (Ant). Python PYRESAMPLE is 
>   used to derive a 3.125km grid according to the (corner) grid coordinates 
>   provided by NSIDC (http://nsidc.org/data/polar_stereo/ps_grids.html).
>
> - Polar stereographic projection with the projection plane intersecting 
>     the earth at 70 degree and using the Hughes ellipsoid; with the radius of 
>     6378.273 km and an eccentricity (e) of 0.081816153, follows a semi-minor axis 
>     of 6356.88944891.
> - Corner coordinates northern hemisphere ('Arc'):
>
>   lon 168.35, lat 31.00,
>     lon 102.34, lat 31.38,
>     lon  -9.98, lat 34.36,
>     lon -80.74, lat 33.94
> - Corner coordinates southern hemisphere ('Ant'):
>
>   lon  -42.24, lat -39.25,
>     lon   42.24, lat -39.25,
>     lon  135.00, lat -41.46,
>     lon -135.00, lat -41.46
>
> The values for semi-major axis, semi-minor axis, projection plane, and the >corner 
>   coordinates are used to calculate the pixel loacations with the PYRESAMPLE >package.
>
> The geographic coordinates are provided in the following netCDF-file:
>   **LongitudeLatitudeGrid_3.125km_Arctic.nc**

The polar stereographic projection details are the same as my NSIDC projection, but I don't know what to do with these corner coordinates.

I downloaded the "LongitudeLatitudeGrid_3.125km_Arctic.nc" file. It projects neatly on top of my other NetCDFs, and I can make raster layers for latitude and longitude, but how do I use these to build the coordinate system into rasters from the NetCDFs?

Comment: My .nc files display well in Panoply, but not in NOAA's Weather and Climate Toolkit, interestingly enough.